# Why R package Googlesheets4 won't recognize my credentials...?

Tags: r, google-sheets, googlesheets4

```
#Google Components####
> library(devtools)
> #devtools::install_github("tidyverse/googlesheets4")
> library(googlesheets4)
> library(googledrive)
> #library(googlesheets)
> library(gargle)
> library(httr)
> options(httr_oob_default=TRUE)
> options(gargle_oauth_email = "mygmail@gmail.com",
+         gargle_oauth_cache = "/home/cpac/")
> options(gargle_oauth_email = TRUE)
> drive_auth()
Enter authorization code: 4/yAGk1Clz0D6r5bSw0ffTPpLdGU-YaOSGgJIgb7ruy3zidJxijw--EJk
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `drive_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
  * Call `drive_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
```

So I can get a pop up to occur that asks for login information and generates an auth code for me, but as soon as it's entered it's rejected by R saying it still can't get my Google credentials... any help is very very much appreciated... all my reports run into googlesheets and I can't figure out why this is not longer working...